# max and min of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1-e^{x^2+y^2}$ on $D$

Tags: real-analysis

I have to find $\min/\max_D f(x,y)$, where  $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2+1-e^{x^2+y^2}$ and 
$D$ is $[0,1]\times [0,1]$ . $f$ is continuous on $D$ (compact set) so global max and min exist. If I study the gradient it is null at the origin but $(0,0) \in \partial D$. In order to study the stationary points on $\partial D$ can I use the fact that $f$ is a radial function?

Comment: Yes, you can use that $f=g\circ  h$, where $g(r)=r+1-e^r$ and $h(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. Therefore the extremal values of $f$ on $D$ are the same as those of $g$  on $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, spherical coordinates make this question easier. You have

$$
f(r,\phi)=r^2+1-e^{r^2}
$$
so $f$ only depends on one variable which you can even call $q = r^2$. Indeed
$$
f(q)=q+1-e^{q}
$$
and
$$
f'(q)=1-e^{q}
$$
so a global maximum on D will be at $q=0$, i.e. $x=y=0$.

As $f$ decreases with $q$, the minimum is at the largest $q=r^2$ on D which is
attained at $x=y=1$.